# How to use function in where with ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I wrote a where function to check if product have some functionality and find a product with max price.

My simply models look like this:

```
 public class Product
 {
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Functionality> Functionalities { get; set; }
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
 }

 public class Functionality
 {
    public long FunctionalityID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
 }

 public class Price
 {
    public long PriceID { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
 }
```

then my sync function to find correct product look like this:

```
 public List<Product> GetList(ProductFiltersDto filters)
 {
    return _context.Product
        .Include(x => x.Functionality)
        .Include(x => x.Price)
        .Where(x =>
            CheckCollectionFilter(x.Functionality.Select(f => f.FunctionalityID), filters.Functionalities) &&
            CheckMaximumPrice(x.Prices , filters.MaxPrice)
         )
         .ToList();

 }
```

below my where function:

```
private bool CheckCollectionFilter<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, List<T> filterCollection)
{
    if (filterCollection != null)
    {
        var result = true;
        foreach (var filterValue in filterCollection)
        {
            if (!collection.Contains(filterValue))
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
     }
     else
     {
         return true;
     }
}

private bool CheckMaximumPrice(List<Price> prices, decimal? avalibleMinPrice)
{
    return avalibleMinPrice.HasValue && prices.Count > 0 ? prices.Min(x => x.Value) <= avalibleMinPrice : true;
}
```

For above code everything work fine. But when i change `ToList()` to `ToListAsync()` i got a error

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Int64]' 
>   cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int64]' 
>   of method 'Boolean CheckCollectionFilter[Int64](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int64], 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int64])'
>   Parameter name: arg0

I try few things to change `IEnumerable` to `IAsyncEnumerable` and modify my function to work with asyn version but stil i get error (i dont find a way to change `List<long>` to `IAsyncEnumerable<long>` in where clause).

I read that EF Core Async functions have some limitations but maybe someone know is this can be achiev or for now i should leave this and stick with sync solution?

Comment: Even if you get the code to compile. EF isn't going to be able to translate an expression that's calling out to a custom method into SQL, so the code is just going to fail at runtime anyway.

Comment: @Servy you mean sync or async version or both? If you say about sync this work fine. If in async version i remove functions this work fine too and simple where work to like `where(x  => x.Name = "your_name_here")`

Comment: Apparently EF core, unlike EF, decided that whenever a query can't be translated into SQL it'll just silently pull the whole thing into memory and do the computation in memory, which you most certainly don't want to be doing in a situation like this.  So your query is just silently not working, rather than actually translating the query properly.

Comment: That's right. EF-core silently switches to client-side evaluation when necessary. My understanding is that `ToListAsync` produces an `IAsyncEnumerable` from the database-side evaluated expression which is then handed over to the client method `CheckCollectionFilter`, which obviously fails because `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Servy thanks i will check that

Comment: This sounds like implementation defect/failure of the EF Core client evaluation. But you should try to avoid client evaluation where possible anyway, as mentioned in the Paulo Morgado answer.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you move from `IQueriable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, EntityFramework will execute the query so far on the database server pulling all that data into memory and will execute the rest of the query in memory.

If you want to keep it running in the database server, you must keep the query an `IQueriable<T>` and use expression trees instead of executable code.

You will need to come up with something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CheckCollectionFilter<T>(IEnumerable<T> filterCollection);

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CheckMaximumPrice<T>(decimal? avalibleMinPrice);
```

and change your query to:

```
_context.Product
    .Include(x => x.Functionality)
    .Include(x => x.Price)
    .Where(CheckCollectionFilter(filters.Functionalities))
    .Where(CheckMaximumPrice(filters.MaxPrice))
```

Comment: Generally correct answer. The problem with EF Core client evaluation (enabled by default) though is that there is no clear move from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` - one may not even realize there is such a transition. In contrast EF6 requires the transition to be explicit (via `AsEnumerable()` or similar).

Comment: Well, it might be clear to you and me, but most of the people don't realize that when you use custom method inside `IQueryable<T>` expression tree (`.Where(x => SomeCustomMethod(x.y)`) it's executed in a different context. Btw, that's was just "clarifying" comment, I agree with your solution(UV is by me :)

Comment: I got what you meant, Ivan. I do job interviews and this is commonly lacking knowledge.